# Loading database values in function and html table

Tags: php, mysql

I've created two functions in php, one of which loads data from a MySQL table and creates an array and the other creates an HTML table view from that data.

On my web page, the table loads, and I've even put some dummy data in the html table function to make sure everything works there. My only issue now is getting the data I need from the database loaded correctly and filling the table.

The script is below, and the query returns exactly what I expect. I just need some assistance on building the data from that query and filling the table properly.

Example:
If I run the query with dealer 12345

```
        SELECT count(*)
            FROM new_count n
                inner join dealers d
                on n.dealer_id = d.dealer_num
         WHERE dealer_id = 12345
         and n.start_date between '{$this->py_from}' and '{$this->py_thru}
         union all
         SELECT count(*)
            FROM new_count n
                inner join dealers d
                on n.dealer_id = d.dealer_num
         WHERE dealer_id = 12345 
         and n.start_date between '{$this->cy_from}' and '{$this->cy_thru}
         union all
         SELECT count(*)
            FROM new_count n
                inner join dealers d
                on n.dealer_id = d.dealer_num
         WHERE dealer_id = 12345 
         and n.start_date between '{$this->py_from}' and '{$this->py_yearend}
```

And get this:

250

319

1258

Then the table should look like this:

```
------------------------------
2017 YTD   |  250
2018 YTD   |  319
PCT Change |  27.6%
2017 Full  |  1258
```

Script:

```
private $yyyy;
private $pyyy;
private $py_from;
private $py_thru;
private $py_yearend;
private $cy_from;
private $cy_thru;

function __construct() {
    $this->yyyy = date('Y');
    $this->pyyy = $this->yyyy - 1;
    $this->py_from = "{$this->pyyy}-01-01";
    $this->py_thru = $this->pyyy . '-' . date('m-d');
    $this->py_yearend = "{$this->pyyy}-12-31";
    $this->cy_from = "{$this->yyyy}-01-01";
    $this->cy_thru = date('Y-m-d'); 
}

private function loadCount($custno){

$custno += 0;
$this->mysqlConnect();

$sql1 = " 
                    SELECT count(*)
            FROM new_count n
                inner join dealers d
                on n.dealer_id = d.dealer_num
         WHERE dealer_id = 12345
         and n.start_date between '{$this->py_from}' and '{$this->py_thru}
         union all
         SELECT count(*)
            FROM new_count n
                inner join dealers d
                on n.dealer_id = d.dealer_num
         WHERE dealer_id = 12345 
         and n.start_date between '{$this->cy_from}' and '{$this->cy_thru}
         union all
         SELECT count(*)
            FROM new_count n
                inner join dealers d
                on n.dealer_id = d.dealer_num
         WHERE dealer_id = 12345 
         and n.start_date between '{$this->py_from}' and '{$this->py_yearend} 
       ";


$result1 = mysql_connect($this->mysqli, $sql1);

$this->placeSnap = array();

    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
        $this->placeSnap[$row1[]];
        $this->isloaded = true;
    }

    if ($this->placeSnap['PY_YTD'] == 0) {
        $this->placeSnap['PCT'] = 0;
    } else {
        $this->placeSnap['PCT'] = ($this->placeSnap['CY_YTD']-$this->placeSnap['PY_YTD']) / $this->placeSnap['PY_YTD'];
        $this->placeSnap['PCT'] = round( $this->placeSnap['PCT'] * 100, 0);
        $this->placeSnap['PCT'] = min(array($this->placeSnap['PCT'], 999));
    }
}


/**
 * HTML for placement snapshot table
 * 
 * @param int $custno
 * @param string $header
 * @return string
 */
function countHTML($custno, $header='Placement Snapshot') {

    $this->loadCount($custno);

    $h1 = "<table class='customer-volume-snapshot-table'>";
    $h1 .= "<thead><tr><th colspan='2'>" . htmlspecialchars($header) . "</th></tr></thead>";
    $h1 .= "<tbody>";
    $h1 .= "<tr><td>{$this->pyyy} YTD</td><td style='text-align: right;'>" /*This should show count for all records for that $custno for 2017 YTD*/"</td></tr>";
    $h1 .= "<tr><td>{$this->yyyy} YTD</td><td style='text-align: right;'>" . /*This should show count for all records for 2018 YTD*/ . "</td></tr>";
    $h1 .= "<tr><td>Percent Change</td><td style='text-align: right;'>{$this->placeSnap['PCT']}%</td></tr>";/*Percentage change between the two*/
    $h1 .= "<tr><td>{$this->pyyy} Full Year</td><td style='text-align: right;'>" . number_format($this->placeSnap['PY_FULL']) . "</td></tr>"; /*Count for full year 2017*/
    $h1 .= "</tbody></table>";

    //Dummy Data to ensure table loading properly
    // $h1 = "<table class='customer-volume-snapshot-table'>";
    // $h1 .= "<thead><tr><th colspan='2'>" . htmlspecialchars($header) . "</th></tr></thead>";
    // $h1 .= "<tbody>";
    // $h1 .= "<tr><td>{$this->pyyy} YTD</td><td style='text-align: right;'>215</td></tr>";
    // $h1 .= "<tr><td>{$this->yyyy} YTD</td><td style='text-align: right;'>189</td></tr>";
    // $h1 .= "<tr><td>Percent Change</td><td style='text-align: right;'>12%</td></tr>";
    // $h1 .= "<tr><td>{$this->pyyy} Full Year</td><td style='text-align: right;'>532</td></tr>";
    // $h1 .= "</tbody></table>";

    return $h1;
}
```

UPDATE:

WHen I do a print_r on the result I get:

```
(
[count(*)] => 0
)
```

Comment: That's incomplete but I was going to use that for an alias in my query which I ended up using. I left it to show how I was using that array but I should have removed it probably. I think I was originally using  a date range in my query and I was going to equate it to something there

Comment: Can you do a `print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1))` and add the result to the question?

Comment: I added it above, that may be part of my problem and I should have done this before. I ran the same query with dummy values in mysql workbench and get 0,28 and 52 respectively

Comment: Change the query to `SELECT count(*) AS n1` .. `SELECT count(*) AS n2` .. etc and try again. I think it overwrites the index `count(*)`. With the adjustment you should receive an array with 3 values.

Comment: Trying that now. That just did the same thing, but with n1 as the array index. I'm going to play with it for a second

Comment: I mean change the 3 `SELECT count(*)`, each of them having a different `AS` name. Also take a good look at the color of the SQL code. It's missing some `'` quotes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166353/discussion-between-xorifelse-and-tom-n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly a few things that can be improved on this code, but lets focus on the issue.

As I suspected that the data returned from the query is not complete.

```
$sql1 = " 
     SELECT count(*) AS n1
        FROM new_count n
            inner join dealers d
            on n.dealer_id = d.dealer_num
     WHERE dealer_id = 12345
     and n.start_date between '{$this->py_from}' and '{$this->py_thru}'
     union all
     SELECT count(*) AS n2
        FROM new_count n
            inner join dealers d
            on n.dealer_id = d.dealer_num
     WHERE dealer_id = 12345 
     and n.start_date between '{$this->cy_from}' and '{$this->cy_thru}'
     union all
     SELECT count(*) AS n3
        FROM new_count n
            inner join dealers d
            on n.dealer_id = d.dealer_num
     WHERE dealer_id = 12345 
     and n.start_date between '{$this->py_from}' and '{$this->py_yearend}'
   ";
```

It was missing some quotes and selecting multiple counts will overwrite the previous `SELECT` due to the union unless you `SELECT` it `AS`.

With this adjustment, you shall receive an array with 3 values. The ones you need to build up your table.

Since you only expect 1 result, change the code to the following:

```
if(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) != false){
  // There is a result.
} else {
  // There is no result.
}
```